# Which is better way to introduce variables in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android

Does the first example produce more efficient code
than the second in Java/Android and in generally in Java?

At least the first example can not be slower than second,
I think..

I do not care here that the variable v may live longer time in first
example, perhaps eating memory for a longer time.

Of course it is true that second way of doing is more readable
if you have more complicated code with several inner blocks.
Also that is not the issue here.

```
MyType v;
for(int i=0;i<bigCount;++i)
{
  v = <value produced for i>;
  //do something with v
}


for(int i=0;i<bigCount;++i)
{
  MyType v = <value produced for i>;
  //do something with v
}
```

Comment: maybe you can check it, try to measure time elapsed and memory usage for both loops

Comment: Write the code that is the cleanest (i.e. the second one). Most of the time, cleanest code means faster code. And in this case, my guess is that it's a micro-optimization that won't have any significant impact.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose the second option because the `v` variable scope is inside the `for` loop. It doesn't need to be used anywhere outside.

This way, the objects that are created and assigned to `v` are eligible for garbage collection earlier. Or at least the last one will be eligible faster than in the first piece of code.

Comment: I never said that in the first case it won't be eligible for GC. I just said that in the first case, it is eligible earlier.

Comment: Actually, this is not always true. Many JVM implementations, including the ORacle one, allow [invisible references](http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html) to come into existance. In practice this is very rare, but possible. A reference going out of scope in the sense of Java language variable scope does not always mean that the reference also goes out of scope in the implementation (the actual low-level stack that stores your variables in the JVM). In most cases I would care more about coding style than such subtleties, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a minimal example:

```
public void option1() {
    String s;
    for (int i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
        s = String.valueOf(i);
    }
}

public void option2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < foo; i++) {
        String s = String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
```

And found that the generated bytecode is identical for both:

`option1()` :

```
 0 iconst_0
 1 istore_2
 2 goto 13 (+11)
 5 iload_2
 6 invokestatic #17 <java/lang/String/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/String;>
 9 astore_1
10 iinc 2 by 1
13 iload_2
14 aload_0
15 getfield #23 <MethodTest/foo I>
18 if_icmplt 5 (-13)
21 return
```

---

`option2()` :

```
 0 iconst_0
 1 istore_1
 2 goto 13 (+11)
 5 iload_1
 6 invokestatic #17 <java/lang/String/valueOf(I)Ljava/lang/String;>
 9 astore_2
10 iinc 1 by 1
13 iload_1
14 aload_0
15 getfield #23 <MethodTest/foo I>
18 if_icmplt 5 (-13)
21 return
```

My guess is, if the compiler sees, that the variable created before the loop is never used after the loop, it just pulls it's definition into the loop. So in your case, neither is more efficient. So go with the one that's more readable (`option2()`).

Answer (score 0):

to prevent multiple allocations, you can close the variable in it's own scope like this:

```
{
  MyType v;
  for(int i=0;i<bigCount;++i)
  {
    v = <value produced for i>;
    //do something with v
  }
}
```

`v` will be collected by the `GC` after this block